# How can I get column data to be added based on a group designation using R?

Tags: r, aggregate-functions, calculated-columns

The data set that I'm working with is similar to the one below (although the example is of a much smaller scale, the data I'm working with is 10's of thousands of rows) and I haven't been able to figure out how to get R to add up column data based on the group number.  Essentially I want to be able to get the number of green(s), blue(s), and red(s) added up for all of group 81 and 66 separately and then be able to use that information to calculate percentages.

```
txt <- "Group Green Blue Red Total
81 15 10 21 46
81 10 10 10 30
81 4 8 0 12
81 42 2 2 46
66 11 9 1 21
66 5 14 5 24 
66 7 5 2 14
66 1 16 3 20
66 22 4 2 28"

dat <- read.table(textConnection(txt), sep = " ", header = TRUE)
```

I've spent a good deal of time trying to figure out how to use some of the functions on my own hoping I would stumble across a proper way to do it, but since I'm such a new basic user I feel like I have hit a wall that I cannot progress past without help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is via `aggregate`.  Assuming your data is in an object `x`:

```
aggregate(. ~ Group, data=x, FUN=sum)
#   Group Green Blue Red Total
# 1    66    46   48  13   107
# 2    81    71   30  33   134
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have been able to get it to run the aggregate function, but I don't see a display along the lines of your example.  Is there another command I'm missing?

Comment: @nlandis: My guess is that you're assigning the result (i.e. `foo <- aggregate(...)`).  If you want to print the result, just type `foo`.

Comment: @nlandis - did you assign the function to a new object (i.e. `results <- aggregate(...)`? R doesn't generally return a lot of information to the console if you assign a new object. Type the name of the object if you want to return it to screen.

Comment: I didn't assign a new object to it, but I forgot to mention that after I submit the aggregate function the next line shows up as a + and I wasn't sure what to enter here either.

Comment: @nlandis the "+" on a new line means R is expecting input.  It usually means you have unmatched parenthesis, brackets, or curly braces.

Comment: @ Joshua Ulrich Ok, I guess my confusion is because I am entering(    aggregate(. ~ Group, data=x, FUN=sum)         ) and cannot find an unmatched parenthesis.  Thanks to everyone for all of the help.

Comment: @all I actually seem to have found a solution.  Since I was using the program Rstudio, it expected me to use the column heading assigned by Rstudio, instead of my column heading in the data set.  When I swapped to Rcmdr I was able to do it based on the headings that I had provided with my data.  Thanks to everyone who responded to this post, I am exceeding thankful for all the input.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the answers above are perfect examples of how to address this type of problem. Two other options exist within `reshape` and `plyr`

```
library(reshape)
cast(melt(dat, "Group"), Group ~ ..., sum)

library(plyr)
ddply(dat, "Group", function(x) colSums(x[, -1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that @Joshua's answer is neater, but two functions you should learn are `apply` and `tapply`. If `a` is your data set, then:

```
## apply calculates the sum of each row
> total = apply(a[,2:4], 1, sum)
## tapply calculates the sum based on each group
> tapply(total, a$Group, sum)
 66  81 
107 134
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.  While I've been trying to work the aggregate function out I've been trying the apply and tapply functions, but haven't quite figured them out yet.